# Android TelephonyManager listener for phone call state

Tags: android, kotlin, telephonymanager, android-audiomanager

I'd like to setup a listener for when my app initiates a phone call. I need to know the state of the call so that I can enable speaker phone with, I believe, `AudioManager`. I am not sure how to create the listener though and AudioManager. All of the examples I've found are in java rather than kotlin. Below is relevant current code:

```
class PhoneCall : AppCompatActivity() {
    private fun placeCall() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val telephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
            telephonyManager.listen(CallListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE) //Not sure how to create CallListener? Is it a new class or object or something else?
            val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(phoneNumber))
            startActivity(callIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"All of the examples I've found are in java rather than kotlin"_ Android Studio can convert Java code to Kotlin for you. Try pasting some Java code into a Kotlin source file and it should ask you if you want it converted to Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Michael. I didn't know AS could do that.